# SharePoint ServerContext vs. SPContext

Tags: sharepoint

In what scenarios should you use ServerContext over SPContext (and vice versa)? What advantages/disadvantages/limitations are presented? I can't seem to find a good deal of information on this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From MSDN:

> ServerContext Class
>   (Microsoft.Office.Server)
>       Provides run-time methods for shared services in Microsoft Office
>   SharePoint Server 2007.

1. First of all, as I can see,
   ServerContext is available only in
   MOSS.
2. The [example in mentioned MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.server.servercontext.aspx)
   site shows that to get shared
   services userprofiles, you need
   ServerContext.

Those are 2 different classes, not even inherited one by other. Can you use ServerContext to get current list item, list, web or site instance? Compare [SPContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spcontext_members.aspx) and [ServerContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.server.servercontext_members.aspx) members and you'll find out the differences yourself.